# Content synchronization Options

Tags: razl

I am using `Sitecore 9 update 2`. I have a large amount of data to be synchronized from the Production environment to a QA environment.

I am using below two approaches:

1. Sync using `RAZL 4.0`
2. Package uploading

Both are taking a lot of time. Is there any other approach available for the same?

We are not using Unicorn or TDS we have centralized Database for Sitecore items.

Comment: Like https://jeffdarchuk.com/2016/10/24/sitecore-sidekick-content-migrator/ ?

Comment: restoring the database from PROD to QA is not an option?